# Is it bad practice to continually try to insert existing key values

Tags: java, sql, oracle, entity-relationship

I am curious to know on two levels the following details.

1. Is it considered bad practice or is it worst performance to continually try to insert duplicate data and allowing the dbms to enforce an entity's constraints to deny those inserts.  OR is it better to do some sort of SELECT COUNT(1) and only insert if count is not 1.
2. Assuming that from the first item it is more efficient from dbms perspective to enforce an entity's constraints and not make multiple calls.  Will the application code (Java, .NET, etc) suffer a greater performance impact due to code unnecessarily heading into exception block even though the exception will not be handled.

Possible Duplicate: [Inserting data into SQL Table with Primary Key. For dupes - allow insert error or Select first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411575/inserting-data-into-sql-table-with-primary-key-for-dupes-allow-insert-error-o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of performance, you are better off using the in-database feature to enforce constraints.

When you attempt to enforce the constraint outside the database you have two issues.  The first is that you have overhead of running a separate query, returning the results, and performing logic -- several database operations.  Using the constraint, on the other hand, might do the same work, but it does it all inside the database without the extra overhead of passing things back and forth.

Second, when you attempt to enforce the constraint yourself, you introduce race conditions.  This means that you might run the `count()` and it returns 0.  Another transaction, meanwhile, inserts the value and then your insert fails anyway.  You really want to avoid such race conditions.  One solution, of course, is to put all the logic in a single transaction.  This introduces its own overhead.

Comment: Good point about the race conditions.  For the most part we would only be having 1 application with 1 connection running inserts in a serial fashion, but in future it could become an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do a select and then insert each time that will be considerably slower as it requires two round trips. The cost to check an exception is nothing compared to the time required to do a database statement.

Some databases allow "upsert" statements that allow you to do both update and then insert if it doesnt exist as one call.

Really if you are doing this a lot you need to step back and think about the overall algorithm and architecture. Why are you constantly trying to insert values that already exist and is there something you can change so that it isn't happening at all - rather than handling the failure at the database point.

Comment: Here are some more details about why we would be constantly trying to insert the same values.  We have a complex production environment that has a fixed logging structure for transactions (web service requests).  From those production logs we are creating some email reports and flat file reports.  We want to start leveraging a database to unlock more data points.  Because the fields in our reports are fixed we want to let the constraints "auto-document" our environment.  We don't want any manual overhead for managing what the environment looks like.  I would say 3% of inserts are duplicates.

Comment: If its only a low number of duplicates don't worry about it. If you really do want to avoid it you could just keep a local HashSet or HashMap with the ones you have sent and don't send them again if so. You would get some duplicates each time the program was restarted but it would prevent it after that at the cost of some memory.

Comment: Even though 3% it would still be about 1000 inserts every 5 minutes.  A local hashset/map sounds like a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just you increased round trip time. One time check and other time insert if not duplicate.
May be it is not good. But what about to `catch exception and handle it`, `time comparison` between *first check then inset* and catching an `Exception` has much of difference.

**Edit:**
One issue may rise in First check and then inset is `synchronization`. May be some thread update/Insert the data before your thread when you checked that there is no duplication, result will be exception at the end. So you must tackle that can not leave.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would probably write a cursor to check that a record exists. To me it is a cleaner approach than relying on an Exception in order to control your program flow. Yes, there is a performance implication, but it is likely to be marginal. Clean, readable code would take the priority for me.